# Define diminished chord as a roman numeral with JFugue

Tags: java, jfugue

So I want to have a diminished seven chord, as it is the diatonic in major mode and often used in place of the major seven in minor mode. [This site](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/novak/cs314/jfugue-chapter2.pdf) says that diminished chords can be defined by using `dim` after the chord name, but this only works with explicit letter names as far as I can tell. Is there any way to get it to apply to roman numerals?

The following program:

```
ChordProgression cp = new ChordProgression("vii");
cp.setKey("C");
System.out.println(cp.getChords()[0].toHumanReadableString());
cp = new ChordProgression("vii*");
System.out.println(cp.getChords()[0].toHumanReadableString());
cp = new ChordProgression("viidim");
System.out.println(cp.getChords()[0].toHumanReadableString());
```

Outputs:

```
B4MIN
C4MIN
C4DIM
```

The output should be `B4DIM`.

Comment: The diminshed seventh chord is not 'the diatonic in major mode', whatever that means. Hard to see why you're expecting 'B4DIM' when you are only using 'dim' in one chord, and hard to see why the output for that chord, which *does* contain 'DIM', doesn't satisfy you.

Comment: @EJP Sorry I meant _seven_, not seven_th_. I'll correct my question.

Comment: 'Seventh' is correct, and you haven't addressed my comment in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To produce a diminished chord from `ChordProgression`, use 'o' or 'd' at the end of the Roman numerals.

```
ChordProgression cp = new ChordProgression("viid").setKey("C");
System.out.println(cp);
```

This code produces `B4DIM`.